# Creating "modes" in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, configuration, dreamweaver

I'm a Dreamweaver and php noobie (I'm a C++ developer), I'd like to know if there's a way to define different "modes" (e.g. Debug, Release, etc.)? For example, I'd like to be able to have a Debug and Release mode that would affect my database connection and other variables, I'd like to be able to use this in code by doing something like:

```
if($DEBUGGING)
{ // set connection to debug connection string
}
else
{ // set connection to release connection string
}
```

Comment: usually you then just define some config file and put there dependent on your environment the values. (like e.g. `const DEBUGGING = 1;` or you directly your right credentials in that file)

Comment: that's disappointing, is there an ide that has the capability to define "modes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/define

**header.php**

```
define('DEV_ENV', 'staging');
```

**other files**

```
if( !defined('DEV_ENV') ) { die('error message here'); }

switch(DEV_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    $conn_string = "foo";
    break;
  case 'staging':
    $conn_string = "bar";
    break;
  case 'development':
    $conn_string = "baz";
    break;
  default:
    die('error message here');
}
```

Comment: I'd really prefer using `const`, but everything else is fine :-)

Comment: @bwoebi `const` is only valid in an object context.

Comment: @Sammitch That's wrong. Try it yourself. `const DEV_ENV = 'staging';` — outside of any class.

Comment: @bwoebi hrm, looks like it *is* valid for [PHP>=5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)